# Make HTML form and table by using JavaScript code.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to make Form and Table using JavaScript code in HTML page. But the code in not in the correct way. So I need to make the Form and Table in JavaScript way. And HTML code of the Form and Table are display as cooment in the following code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
           function clickFunction(e) {
  document.getElementsByName('inputvalue')[0].innerHTML =
  document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
  e.preventDefault(); //fallback
  return false;
  }
    </script>
    <!-- <form>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="clickFunction(event)">
    </form> -->
    <script>
        var form = $('<form>');
        var input = $('<input>',{
        type: 'button',
        name: 'name' });
        var button = $('<input>',{
        type: 'button',
        value: 'Done',
        onclick: 'clickFunction(event)'
        });
        input.appendTo(form);
        button.appendTo(form);
        form.appendTo('<body>');
    </script>

    <!-- <table border="1">
        <tr><td>Data input: </td><td><label name="inputvalue" > </label></td></tr>
    </table> -->

    <script>
var table = $('<table>');
        var tr = $('<tr>');
        var td_1 = $('<td>',{
        text: 'Data input'
        });
        var td_2 = $('<td>');
        var label = $('<label>',{
        name: 'inputvalue' });
        label.appendTo(td_2);
        td_2.appendTo(tr);
        td_1.appendTo(tr);
        tr.appendTo(table);
        table.appendTo('<body>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, you want to use jQuery without including it?

Comment: Do I need to use JQuery link here?

Comment: try full code in my answer.

Comment: thank you. I need to add JQuery in this code. :)

Comment: I have add your code . It works now. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jQuery library like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your page and use `.appendTo('body');` instead of `.appendTo('<body>');`

```js
function clickFunction(e) {
  document.getElementsByName('inputvalue')[0].innerHTML =
    document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
  e.preventDefault(); //fallback
  return false;
}

var form = $('<form>');
var input = $('<input>', {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'name'
});
var button = $('<input>', {
  type: 'button',
  value: 'Done',
  onclick: 'clickFunction(event)'
});
input.appendTo(form);
button.appendTo(form);
form.appendTo('body');

var table = $('<table>');
var tr = $('<tr>');
var td_1 = $('<td>', {
  text: 'Data input'
});
var td_2 = $('<td>');
var label = $('<label>', {
  name: 'inputvalue'
});
label.appendTo(td_2);
td_2.appendTo(tr);
td_1.appendTo(tr);
tr.appendTo(table);
table.appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Full Code

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function clickFunction(e) {
      document.getElementsByName('inputvalue')[0].innerHTML =
        document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
      e.preventDefault(); //fallback
      return false;
    }

    var form = $('<form>');
    var input = $('<input>', {
      type: 'text',
      name: 'name'
    });
    var button = $('<input>', {
      type: 'button',
      value: 'Done',
      onclick: 'clickFunction(event)'
    });
    input.appendTo(form);
    button.appendTo(form);
    form.appendTo('body');

    var table = $('<table>');
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var td_1 = $('<td>', {
      text: 'Data input'
    });
    var td_2 = $('<td>');
    var label = $('<label>', {
      name: 'inputvalue'
    });
    label.appendTo(td_2);
    td_2.appendTo(tr);
    td_1.appendTo(tr);
    tr.appendTo(table);
    table.appendTo('body');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the appendTo body functions

```
//form.appendTo('<body>');
form.appendTo('body');

//table.appendTo('<body>');
table.appendTo('body');
```

Comment: I have tried but it does not work after I modified the code as you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("<html><body><form><table border='1'><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table></form></body></html>");
</script>
```

whatever html content you would like to use in javascript, just paste it inside document.write();

Comment: I need separately each HTML contains.Then I can add them as I wish. Therefore< I couldn't use like this.